# jQuery custom toggle function issue

Tags: jquery, toggle

[**please refer to the fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtqA2/) I have a problem when using the jquery function toggle to custom my needs. My toggle just expand the height of a div by run time.
i have a JS code like this :

```
    $(function () {
       $(".enlarge").click(function(){
         var btn = $(this),
             text = btn.siblings('.text'),
             collapsed = text.hasClass('collapsed'),
             height = collapsed ? text[0].scrollHeight : $('<div>', {'class': 'text collapsed'}).css('height');

             var $container = $('#container');

             var currentLargeDetailBox = btn.closest('.large-detail-box');
             var currentBigBox = btn.closest('.big-box');

             var newHeightForExpand = height - 260 + currentLargeDetailBox.height();

             text.animate({'height': height}, 400, function() {

                text.toggleClass('collapsed'); 
                text.css('height', ''); 
                btn.text(collapsed ? 'Show Less' : '...(Show More)');

             });

         btn.toggle(function () {           
            currentLargeDetailBox.height(newHeightForExpand);
            currentBigBox.height(newHeightForExpand);
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
         }, function () {
            currentLargeDetailBox.css('height', '');
            currentBigBox.css('height', '');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        });

  });   
});
```

Can someone see the problem of my code and tell me?  the strange thing is is if i use the "text" instead of the "btn", the custom toggle function works. like this:

```
        text.toggle(function () {           
            currentLargeDetailBox.height(newHeightForExpand);
            currentBigBox.height(newHeightForExpand);
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
         }, function () {
            currentLargeDetailBox.css('height', '');
            currentBigBox.css('height', '');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        });
```

Thanks and welcome for any comment.

Comment: Possibly relevant: ["The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has been called on the element."](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: But without any HTML it's difficult for us to reproduce your problem. Try building a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) we can test.

Comment: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qtqA2/) the example code of fiddle is here, thanks...

Comment: Seems to work fine.  What exactly is wrong?

Comment: the big box will not expand while show more is clicked. the hiding text shows but the outer container doesn't expand until the next time you click. and also the custom toggle function is triggered 2 times for each click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're adding the `btn.toggle` event handler **inside** of the click handler -- which not only means it's not available on the first click, but you're adding **another** `.toggle` event handler on each subsequent click.

Try using the `if (collapsed)` Boolean test you already have:

```
$(".enlarge").click(function () {
  var btn = $(this),
    text = btn.siblings('.text'),
    collapsed = text.hasClass('collapsed'),
    height = collapsed ? text[0].scrollHeight : $('<div>', {
      'class': 'text collapsed'
    }).css('height');

  var currentLargeDetailBox = btn.closest('.large-detail-box');
  var newHeightForExpand = height - 260 + currentLargeDetailBox.height();

  text.animate({
    'height': height
  }, 400, function () {
    text.toggleClass('collapsed');
    text.css('height', '');
    btn.text(collapsed ? 'Show Less' : '...(Show More)');
  });

  if (collapsed) {
    alert("1");
    currentLargeDetailBox.height(newHeightForExpand);
  } else {
    alert("2");
    currentLargeDetailBox.css('height', '');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pkjpt/